# How do I install AMD drivers for rx480 card?

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers, intel, amd, radeon

I have had a really difficult transition from Windows to Linux for the last month or so I've been toying around with different distros, and with all of them have yet to been able  to install the AMD GPU drivers on any OS! So I am actually going to go in and try Elementary OS this time give it another wack and see if I can go about getting the correct drivers installed correctly. I am running a biostar tb 85 with a I 5 quad core processor 8 gigabytes of RAM and of course my Sapphire Nitro RX 480. On a side note I can't find any of the other drivers for this thing either the chipset included as well as Lan drivers.

Comment: Currently you cannot install the AMD drivers for the RX480. It seems AMD cards just use the Open Source drivers. I currently have a Rx 480 and an AMD HD 5750. Both of which have to use the default drivers Elementary provides. I have not had issues gaming because of this, things still run smooth.  DO NOT try to force install the AMD Ubuntu Drivers for your Rx 480, it will give you the black screen of death on boot and then you have to find a way to uninstall your newly borked driver.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps to install amdgpu-pro drivers for Radeon RX 480:

1) Download driver https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz

2) Go to your Downloads directory `cd ~/Downloads`

3) Unpack the driver file `tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655.tar.xz`

4) Go to the unpacked file `cd ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-17.50-511655`

5) Open the file `amdgpu-install` with a text editor and change the following line, so you wont get the "Unsupported OS" error:

```
case "$ID" in
    ubuntu)
```

change it into this

```
case "$ID" in
    elementary)
```

6) Now install dirvers `./amdgpu-install -y`

Comment: I did that but after that my computer didnt boot. I had to boot in recovery mode, start root terminal and uninstall drivers so that my computer could boot again. Now I there is a message everytime I boot that says something about time engine not found. Do you know why is that? My graphics card is Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265]. Sorry for language, I dont speak english very well.